# Smartphone turns off my monitor when placed on a specific position?

Tags: laptop, display, android, mobile-phone

I am not sure what the hell is going on, neither I know where to ask.
For me it looks like phenomenon, but it often ends up being completely explanatory.

---

I've discovered that if I place my SAMSUNG Galaxy S4 mini smartphone somewhere in the right of the DELL Inspiron (n series) touchpad, it turns off the monitor. I made sure the mobile devise has nothing turned on (such as wifi, bluetooth etc)

---

DETAILS:
It turns off the laptop's monitor when it keeps vertical proximity to the hotspot(s) not larger than an inch.

---

Who has any idea what this is about ?

Comment: Does your phone have a magnetic case?

Comment: No, only the phone itself it is. I remember placing an interaction speaker over that place of the laptop and there it worked. Though I don't see what this has to do with the laptop's monitor.. and also my mobile devise is certainly not an interaction speaker.

Comment: @CanadianLuke Ooops, yes, vtc.  This could also answer other questions that request a way to turn off the laptop screen via a utility "stick a magnet near the touchpad" :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Inspirons have a magnetic catch for when you close the laptop lid.

They use the magnetic sensor to work out when the lid is closed so the screen no longer needs to be on.

Your phone is triggering the sensor.

Comment: Ohh. This seems like it. Pretty smart discovery, thanks.

Comment: I'd assume it is because of the phone's speaker magnet.
I found the magnet from the monitor, that is right of the camera, if I put my mobile phone close to that magnet, it activates some sort of clock screensaver lol. These two devises are entertaining.

Comment: Heh, that is probably triggering the phones "flip case" magnet sensor. That is the case with a hole in it that shows the time and date and notifications when the flip case is closed